# Multiple Windows using window.open() AND &apos;

Tags: javascript, php, html, window.open

I want to make sure that if a user clicks the button that opens a new window, that window is maintained if they click the button again. Meaning that I want the user to be able to hold multiple copies of the same window open even when opening new (of the same) ones.

At the moment I have this:

```
onclick="window.open(&apos;file.php?game=0&apos;,  &apos;newwindow&apos; , &apos;width=920,height=740&apos;, &apos;resizable=0&apos;)
```

and I read another thread on here that I could just add a counter.

I did so with
$counter = 0; and then put `, &apos;counter++$apos;,` as an argument but that fails to load the entire page.

What am I missing?

Comment: try to create event listener and preserve the counter in the listener , if counter is one , means click only one time do what you what, if couter is two means 2 clicks do multiple winow , and keep the parameters clean

Comment: There's no need to use `&apos;` here. You aren't using a literal `'` anywhere, so you don't need to use an escaped version of it.

Answer (score 1):

`$counter` is a variable … but it looks like a PHP variable.

`'counter++'` is a string literal.

---

If you want a new window each time you run the script, just use the name `_blank`. There's no point to giving the window a name of its own unless you want to open multiple links in the same window.